# use_framework errors in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm a flutter developer and I don't have much idea about iOS. I'm facing errors for the last 2-3 days in two packages. The flutter packages which I am using are - [razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.7](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)  and image_cropper: ^1.4.1 .

Now, [razorpay_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter) is required to set **use_frameworks!** in Podfile else, it will give a file not found an error as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

On the other hand, the [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) packages use [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController) iOS package which throws errors when we add **use_frameworks!** in Podfile. Check the below screenshot.[image]

Also, there is an issue created on [GitHub](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues/429) where people instructed not to add use_framework in Podfile but it is required for the Razorpay package.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum deployment target shouldn't be less than iOS 10.0. If it is then go to "Podfile" and add this line and save the changes:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Then run `pod install` in the project directory i.e `ios`

Comment: Yeah, I already added this and this even not worked for me. Also, I deleted derived files, clean Xcode using cmd+shift+K

Comment: @surajsharma try to run `pod deintegrate` and install again.

Comment: I tried many things like removing and installing. Ex- removing .lock file, podspec file, pod clean cache etc. Nothing worked for me.

Comment: @surajsharma I'm on flutter version: 1.22.5 and using Xcode 12.5.1 and it's working fine for me.

Comment: are you using both the packages?

Comment: @surajsharma Nope, using Razorpay only. Does it work fine without the `image_cropper` package?

Comment: Actually, errors depend on use_framework! . When I included it on Podfile the errors go away from the Razorpay package but occur in TOCropViewController package and vice versa.

Comment: Also, it is written on Razorpay flutter official package to add use_framework! in Podfile.

Comment: @surajsharma use_frameworks! is enabled in the Podfile and it's working.

Comment: Yes, Razorpay works fine with use_framework! enabled in Podfile but image_croper creates a problem.

Comment: @surajsharma I cant install this package in my current setup. Image cropper requires  SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0 and I'm on 2.10.4